# win10 setup disk driver not found

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers

hello I'm trying to install win10. but it doesn't recognize any disk after i click install > advanced > no disk drive has been detected.

it gives an option to load driver from external (CD / USB)

my hard disk is 
ST1000DM003-1CH162

on 
http://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkStation_S30?M=4352-G1G

I've installed on it Ubuntu successfully.

in ubuntu: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`
**partition table scan:**
MBR: MBR only

**bios setup:**
boot priority: [legacy first]
SATA mode: AHCI

**hardware connection:**
 - harddrive seagate connected to SATA SAS (hard drive 1)
 - ODD connected to Sata 1
[motherboard sata ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntPJi.jpg)

I dont have any CD-rom, im trying to find the drivers i found this:
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/workstations/thinkstation-s-series-workstations/thinkstation-s30/downloads
but i think all of the files are exe! and i think win10 requires inf files for the installation?

**Note:**
this PC had win10 installed before but it get curropted and i didnt change BIOS settings.

Comment: You need in disk controller driver loaded from external device (support CD enclosed to motherboard, or download it from vendor's support site).

Comment: GPT or MBR?  Edit your question, do not submit a comment, and include this vital required information necessary to answer your question

Comment: Are you booting with Legacy Mode enabled or in UEFI mode?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've downloaded Intel RSTe SCU/SATA driver for windows which is EXE

installed it and then copied the files into flash drive.

i could load driver from the path:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaHTE.png)

and loaded these drivers in win-10 setup. then the hard-disk appeared.

i dont know if this is right driver or not as installation stuck at 62% after copying files

[62% stuck screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSvSi.jpg)

error code 0x80070017
i dont expect this is not related to original question as i read that this error could be because of hardware drivers compatibility!

the **problem** was fixed by intel SCU RSTS drivers. although they are extracted from exe installation file i found that bad from lenovo not giving this driver alone?.. the 62% was not related to hardware compatibility i think as i've downloaded win 10 to USB memory.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different problem than you originally thought, it sounds like, you have RAID configuration enabled instead of ACHI.  Which would be the only reason you would need to provide the Intel RST drivers.  However, by identifying a new problem within an answer, you have not really answered your own question.

Comment: hello, im not experienced enough to tell, all i know that i ve one hard drive connected to SCU. (after research) ..

Comment: It is a setting in the firmware.  You need to check, edit your question, and supply the information required to answer your question.

Comment: the configuration was actually **[AHCI]** not RAID. @Ramhound